# Question on Ramanujan Summation

Tags: power-series, ramanujan-summation

I know that Ramanujan Summation is used to assign a value to divergent series.

Such as $$\mathfrak R\biggl(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\biggr)=\frac{1}{2}$$

and $$\mathfrak R\biggl(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nn\biggr)=-\frac{1}{4}$$

However, these values can also be obtained by using the geometric and power series, albeit outside of their radius of convergence.

$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nx^n,\;\;x=1$$

and $$-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^nnx^{n-1},\;\;x=1$$

Are there any cases where Ramanujan Summation does not coincide with the results obtained by plugging the value into a power series?

EDIT: Preferably where the power series is defined but does not match the Ramanujan Sum.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$ \mathfrak R\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1\right)= -\frac{1}{2}$$ but $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x}$$ which diverges at $x=1.$

The method you are using is Abel summation, not Ramanujan.

Comment: This is a bit unsatisfying as rather than giving a wrong value it simply is undefined.

Comment: I believe Abel summable implies Ramanujan summable to the same value.

Comment: _"I believe Abel summable implies Ramanujan summable to the same value."_ That is the question OP really wants answered.

Comment: That would be a trivial solution that I overlooked but I am curious if there are cases where the value is defined but do not coincide with the Ramanujan Sum?

Comment: I was under the impression that Ramanujan summation was a strict extension of Abel, so I don't think that's possible, but am not sure. I've looked for a reference, and can't find one, so perhaps it isn't true.

Comment: btw there are many more examples like this... Any of the various zeta function regularizations like $\mathfrak{R} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\right) = -\frac{1}{12},$ etc.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see, much thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem, and hopefully someone better informed than me will chime in on whether it's possible for an abel sum to be defined and not equal to the ramanujan.