# Does Ramanujan summation extend Abel summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation-method, ramanujan-summation

I was under the impression that if a series is Abel summable, then it is Ramanujan summable to the same value, but when I [answered this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540533/question-on-ramanujan-summation/2540540#2540540) and was asked this as a follow-up, I was unable to confirm.

Is it true?

Comment: It seems that Ramanujan summation does not even extend classical summation, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation and then the source http://algo.inria.fr/seminars/sem01-02/delabaere2.pdf (look at proposition 1)

Comment: Oh, it seems that there is more than one summation named after him....

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant, but have you seen Theorem 246 on page 345 (these numbers are not a joke) of Hardy's book? https://archive.org/stream/divergentseries033523mbp#page/n365/ in section 8.11 (pg.191) I believe the method $(B^*)$ is Borel summation, which i think is stronger than Abel?